# Reagent material ui paper elevation

Tags: material-ui, clojurescript, reagent

I don't know how to set the elevation for materia-ui paper in reagent-material-ui (https://github.com/arttuka/reagent-material-ui)

Paper elevation in Material UI: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-paper/#elevation

I tried the trivial:

```
[paper {:variant :outlined :elevation 12} "test 123"]
```

No elevation is rendered:
[no-elevation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOkSu.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was clearly stated in an error I haven't noticed until now.

Outlined variant does not work with elevation. Removed the outlined variant and the elevation was rendered.